# Getting encoded Values in JSON while using Kafka connect :JdbcSourceConnector

Tags: json, oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka Connect in standalone configuration to read data from Oracle.

While reading a message from a topic, I receive the result as JSON. I don't need my values to be encoded inside a JSON object. How can I resolve this?

`connect-standalone.properties`:

```
bootstrap.servers=********:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

`jdbc-kafka-connect.properties`:

```
name=jdbctransconnector
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@**.**.*.***:1521/****?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
connection.user=*******
connection.password=*******
query=select * from(select cast(tab1.PARAM_INSTANCE_ID as NUMERIC(11,0)) AS PARAM_INSTANCE_ID,tab1.entity_id,tab2.param_name,tab1.value from table1 tab1,table2 tab2 where tab1.param_spec_id=tab2.param_basic_spec_id)
tasks.max= 1
auto.create= true
auto.evolve= true
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=PARAM_INSTANCE_ID
topic.prefix=EGPV
```

Sample message from Kafka consumer:

```
{
"PARAM_INSTANCE_ID":"B6frdA==",
"ENTITY_ID":"AXpUSLCacxAucbLv12PipNeV7ag2XAFudUuzxrP1xDvtlnZOuxf8KxSAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
"PARAM_NAME":"Action",
"VALUE":null
}
```

`param_instance_id` and `entity_id` are number columns in source database. How can I get the same format in Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> param_instance_id and entity_id are number columns in source database

The default `numeric.mapping` property is not set, and so numbers are base64 encoded.

Adjust this based on the description available in the documentation, but you can start with `best_fit`

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html

Comment: Thanks for your response @OneCricketeer , I am now able to get actual values.Still when I use table.whitelist instead of query,I am facing the same issue because my source table has number datatype.This numeric.mapping works only with numeric datatype.Please suggest any change for number datatype if you know

Comment: I'm not aware of such a config. I have seen a handful of Github issues in the JDBC connector asking for something like that, though. The alternative solution might include using Debezium or Confluent's Oracle CDC Source rather than JDBC